# Como guardar un callback de un ajax en una variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Buenas noches estoy haciendo 2 peticiones ajax a 2 services la cual logre sacar la información en 2 funciones como hago para unificar las 2 funciones ya que cada una tiene un dato diferente o como guardar cada una de esas funciones en una variable gracias de antemano.

```
function nombre(t,callback) {


            $.ajax({
                url: url1,
                method:'GET',
                type: 'JSON'
            }).done(function (alumnos) {

                var alum = JSON.parse(alumnos);

                var  nnn= alum[t-1].NOMBRE_USUARIO;

                callback(nnn);

                //console.log(nnn);


            });

        }


        function evento(obj,callback) {

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method:'GET',
                type: 'JSON'
            }).done(function (eventos) {

                var even = JSON.parse(eventos);

              var evento = even[obj-1].NOMBRE_EVENTO;

              callback(evento);

              //console.log(evento);

           });

        }

        function mycallback(dato1) {

            var dat1 = dato1;

            console.log(dat1);

        }


        function mycallback1(dato2) {

            var dat2 = dato2;

            console.log(dat2);

            return dato2;

        }


nombre(t,mycallback);
evento(t,mycallback1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema como tal no es debido al llamado de los callbacks, el error en sí, es porque ud tiene mal estructurado el código y no es posible que se haga así, ademas de que no es correcto:

Soluciones funcionales:

**1.** anidar los llamados ajax, así:

```
function consultar(t) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url1,
        method: 'GET',
        type: 'JSON'
    }).done(function(alumnos) {
        var alum = JSON.parse(alumnos);
        var nnn = alum[t - 1].NOMBRE_USUARIO;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'GET',
            type: 'JSON'
        }).done(function(eventos) {
            var even = JSON.parse(eventos);
            var evento = even[obj - 1].NOMBRE_EVENTO;
            finalizar(nnn, evento)                  
        });
    });
}

function finalizar(nombre, evento) {
    console.log(nombre, evento);
}
```

**2.** usar promesas:

Debe usar promesas(aunque los llamados ajax, ya están promisificados), la idea es que anide las funciones `function nombre(t,callback)` y `function evento(obj,callback)` dentro de una promesa y así poder cambiar el callback por un `return`. Le recomiendo usar [Promesas nativas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise), [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html), [Async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) o [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

Debe tener presente que su código es bastante sencillo, por lo que no es conveniente que use una API, es mejor que opte  por la opción 1, o las promesas nativas.

**Anexo:**

Estoy haciendo pruebas con el flujo de información similar al suyo, pero sin ajax; y todo funciona perfecto.

```
function nombre(t, callback) {    
  console.log(1,t)
  callback(t);       
}
function mycallback(dato1) {    
  console.log(2,dato1);
}
nombre("nombre", mycallback);
```

[Ejemplo simple Callbacks](https://codepen.io/cvalencia/pen/XzjKgq?editors=1010)

Comment: Muchas gracias Hasta ahora estoy aprendiendo con jquery pero me ha sido de mucha ayuda su información muchas gracias.